# Apply / deploy New view to multiple libraries

Tags: 2013, list-view, list-template

I just got an insane request dropped onto my desk. On our site we have a section with 15 subsites, each subsite has 5 libraries.

The request was to add a new view with a new column to all of the libraries.
Is there anyway to apply the view to all the libraries at once? 
Or am I looking at a long "fun" project?

They currently have the same columns but the views are not linked as a template or anything (not my doing)

We are using SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Designer 2013
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below powershell

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue

$siteURL = "http://sp14fdev01/"
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL)

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
  foreach($list in $web.Lists) {
    if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {
// the variables `$web` and `$list` already reference the objects you need
      //$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($SiteURL) ;
      //$web = $site.OpenWeb($SiteURL);

// new instance of the list is necessary to avoid the error "Collection was modified"
      $newList = $web.Lists.item($list.ID);

      $viewfields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection 
      $viewfields.Add("DocIcon") 
      $viewfields.Add("LinkFilename") 
      $viewfields.Add("_UIVersionString") 
      $viewfields.Add("FileSizeDisplay") 
      $viewfields.Add("Created") 
      $viewfields.Add("Modified") 
      $viewfields.Add("Editor") 
      [void]$newList.Views.Add("Detailed", $viewfields, "", 100, $true, $true)

      $newList.Update();

// setting the default view
      $view=$newList.Views["Detailed"]
      $view.DefaultView = $true
      $view.Update()
    }
  }

  $web.Dispose();
}

$site.Dispose();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980124/sharepoint-2010-powershell-loop-through-all-document-libraries-create-view-a

also check this:

[How do I create a custom view and apply it to ALL document libraries on Sharepoint 2007 site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69220/how-do-i-create-a-custom-view-and-apply-it-to-all-document-libraries-on-sharepoi)

Comment: Finally getting back to this. It seems we don't have access to Powershell. Any other ideas on how to do this? Even if I had to rebuild all of the libraries so they had a shared/global view that could be updated later would be fine.